# Gradual italics?

Tags: html, css, text, typography

Is there a way to gradually transition from normal text into italics changing the slant angle ever so slightly with each character?

Comment: Is the question about html+css, or about an image with text created in php? In the first case, why the [php] tag? In the second case, which image library are you using?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Just the text. PHP tag because I thought it will have to be done by a back-end programming language.

Comment: I've removed your php tag, since your server side technology is irrelevant for client side text rendering. Your server side tech is only relevant if you render on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robin's idea does work ([**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3395805)), but there are so many things wrong with that fiddle I wasn't sure I could fit them into one comment.

First of all, `span` is an `inline` element and `transform` works on `block` elements. So you either use a `block` element like `div` or `p` or you set `display: block` on the `span`.

**Don't use `skew`**! **Use `skewX`**. `skew` was present in the early drafts and it has been removed since. It isn't even supported by Firefox 14, though it was reintroduced in Firefox 15 due to compatibility reasons and still works in Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Always put the unprefixed version last. [Transforms should be unprefixed](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) in the coming versions of Firefox, Opera and IE.

You also need a dot in front of the class name.

Something like this:

```
<div class="skewme">Tyrannosaurus Rex</div>
```

with the CSS part being simply

```
.skewme {
   -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
      -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
        -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
           transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

In order to gradually transition from the normal text to the slanted text you'll need [**transitions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition) or [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes).

HTML:

```
<div class="skewme1">Tyrannosaurus Rex</div>
```

CSS:

```
.skewme1 {
    -webkit-animation: slowskew 1.5s infinite alternate;
           -moz-animation: slowskew 1.5s infinite alternate;
             -o-animation: slowskew 1.5s infinite alternate;
                animation: slowskew 1.5s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slowskew {
    to { -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slowskew {
    to { -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes slowskew {
    to { -o-transform: skewX(-20deg); }
}
@keyframes slowskew {
    to { transform: skewX(-20deg); }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP was requesting a line of characters, each more italicised that the previous. Well, that’s what I did in my answer. Guess we’ll find out :)

Comment: That's a very interesting idea actually. How it's going to look at then probably depends on the length of the text and on the rate at which the skew angle increases http://dabblet.com/gist/3396122

Answer (score 3):

Your font may well have completely different glyphs for italics and normal text, so even morphing between them using SVG crazy-clever might look weird.

An alternative would be to apply a [CSS3 2D skew transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp). This won't transition between the normal and italic forms, but would just slant the normal form. This may or may not give you a visually-appealing result, depending on your font. It's also not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Not with italics no, you’ve only got a choice of `normal` or `italic` (and `oblique` which has a specific meaning in typography but generally not on standard web fonts).

You could however fake it in a really nasty fashion with CSS transforms. E.g.:

```
<span class="skew0">R</span><span class="skew1">R</span><span class="skew2">R</span><span class="skew3">R</span>
```

and:

```
span { display: inline-block; }
.skew1 { transform: skewX(-5deg); }
.skew2 { transform: skewX(-10deg); }
.skew3 { transform: skewX(-15deg); }
```

`skew()` is in danger of being removed from the spec – it’s already been removed from Mozilla but was added back in due to incompatibility worries – and you’ll obviously need to add in the standard vendor prefixes.

Test at: http://jsfiddle.net/GtQXw/1/

Comment: Oops, my fault. I’ve updated the fiddle with it working, and I’ll edit my answer. Something I forgot is that they’ll need to be either `block` or `inline-block` for the transformation to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - You have to create an image. Otherwise no

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it through an SVG, but then you'll forfeit the browser support you'd get through an image. IE8 and earlier does not support SVGs, IIRC.