# How to transform font-style with CSS3?

Tags: css, animation, fonts, keyframe

I have a one word title that is split in two halves which are animated with @keyframe and meet in the middle of the page.
Problem: I need one of the two halves to transform from regular to italic after it has reached its proper position in the middle of the page.
Since I don't intend to make the title clickable there is no point in using hover.
Is there a way to do this without resorting to javascript...?

Answer (score 5):

As the font-style is [not an animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties#font), you can use a skew tranformation.

```css
h1 span {
  position: relative;
}
#title_part1 {
  animation: part1_move 2s;
}
#title_part2 {
  
  animation: part2_move 2s,part2_skew 4s;
  
  display: inline-block;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

@keyframes part1_move {
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}


@keyframes part2_move {
  from {
    left: 100px;
    }
  to{
    left:0
  }
}

@keyframes part2_skew{
  from {
    transform:skewX(0);
    -ms-transform:skewX(0)
  }
  50%{
    transform:skewX(0);
    -ms-transform:skewX(0)
  }
  to{
    transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-20deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span id="title_part1">The start and </span>
  <span id="title_part2">the end of my title </span>
</h1>
```

Related questions:

[Fade from normal text to italics text smoothly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798821/fade-from-normal-text-to-italics-text-smoothly)

[Gradual italics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027563/gradual-italics)

Comment: I think you missed the `after it has reached its proper position in the middle of the page` But that shouldn't be to hard, just make it two different animations, where the skew animation runs with a delay equal to the duration of the move animation. Nice answer.

Comment: that is corrected, thank you. It could indeed be better to make two animations and a delay for the second.

Comment: @gael - thank you for your help. For some reason I thought "skew" had to do with polygons or shapes.

Comment: it is also skewing text in them! Note that the container have to be a block element. In that case `inline-block` is enough.

Comment: The real reason font-style is not animatable is because animating between regular and italic is not simply a matter of skewing the text in a certain direction. In this case, it produces what is known as a faux italic, wherein the typesetter simply skews the type rather than printing it in an actual italic face, either because the font does not provide an italic face, or because it is otherwise not supported.